# Does Powered Up provide a rechargable battery box?

Tags: powered-up

The older Power Functions electrical system includes the option to purchase a lithium ion rechargeable battery box. Is something like this available for the newer Powered Up system?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't currently available.

The Powered Up team [responded to a question about this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=579&v=oHdQoFW-_ZY) in May 2019. The gist is that they were able to say that the removable battery holder in the hub was designed with a future rechargeable battery in mind. This can also be inferred directly from the design:

[image: battery installation]

They cited several reasons that this isn't yet available, including TLG's strong commitment to product quality and safety, particularly in a product like this that would involve a direct interface to mains power for recharging. The challenges of localizing the charging adapter to all markets was also mentioned.

The team didn't provide a release date, but there was a sense that this would be coming at some point.